# Access to Earth Engine Functions

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need to access to the function `ee.classifier.cart` to understand all the passages of the codes and possibly to modify it for my purposes.

Is there any way or I need to be an Earth Engine Developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the earthengine-api is open source, the interesting code, like the one you're looking for, is not. So unless you're working at Google, you're out of luck.